# Javac is not being recognized even after setting the class path variable

Tags: javac

My problem is that I have set the `bin` path in `Class path variables`. After that
Command Prompt is recognizing "`java`" command but "`javac`" `program` is still not being recognized.

Comment: Possibly daft, but I've done this before hence the suggestion, but you've definitely got a JDK installed and not a JRE? There is actually a 'javac' command to invoke, right?

Comment: make sure you're in the directory where `javac.exe` is located. Default directory if not specified is `"driverletter:\Program Files\java\jdk*\bin\"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are pointing to the "bin" directory of the jdk and NOT jre. Also, as Juned answered, you need to open a new command line after you update the environment variable in "PATH"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have set the `jdk/bin` folder path to your system PATH variable.

Just make sure you re-open the command line because an open command line does refresh itself with the new environment params.

After adding jdk/bin to your PATH, simply launch a new command prompt and type `javac`, java magic should start happening.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin` to Path environmental variable should be done. But you shouldn't insert any space between the previous `;` and the path of bin folder:

- Path: `c:\some name\.....\; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin` ==>WRONG
- Path: `c:\some name\.....\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin` ==>OK